# How do I keep the peak voltage in a coil connected to a signal generator constant, given that I'm changing the frequency?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, frequency

I want to vary the frequency of the A.C supply, and hence change the peak current in the circuit. But V=IR, so won't the peak voltage also be changed if I change the peak current?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at your analysis a little more deeply than that. Your inductor and resistor will be in series according to the lumped circuit analysis that you should be directing your attention at. In that case

$$V=IR+L\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Now I could go for two kinds of mathematical analysis, fourier or laplace. If I would go for Fourier analysis.
$$V(\omega)=I(\omega)R+j\omega LI(\omega)-Li(o)=I(\omega)\left[R+j\omega L\right]-Li(0)$$
Now, iff $$\omega L>>R$$
Then you don't have to worry about $R$ at all, since the drop in resistance created by your resistor is negligible compared to the potential change across your coil because of your changing flux, but also it would be helpful if I could specify a given value of $\omega$, since for extremely low values of $\omega$, the left hand product $\omega L$ could easily become lower than $R$. Hence, this kind of analysis only works when you have periodic signals where the $\omega$ space is discretized and you know about the specific $\omega$ value that you are talking about. Thus depending on the specific omega value you have different net impedences that you can be talking about. I know that I have digressed a bit from your question, but the solution that I would offer to your question is to make sure that your source is a pure sinusoidal signal of very high frequency and that wire which makes the coil is very thick, hence low $R$, while the area across your coil should be very large, hence high $L$. Having a pure sinusoidal signal would help because only two fourier co-efficients exist at the source frequency at opposite ends of the spectrum.